# VB.net success and refresh code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, refresh

I have a page in my site that has 5 different textboxes to add different things to my database. I would like each one to be able to have a success code tied to it, but also be able to refresh the page. I use `Response.Write("<script>alert(" & "'Image Title added successfully'" & ")</script>")` to show the message, but when I add `Response.Redirect("AddToPicklist.aspx")` to it, the success message doesn't display anymore. Is there an easier way to do this is ASP.net?

```
 <tr><td class="title">Image</td></tr>  
    <tr><td>Image Title: </td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtImageTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
<tr><td><asp:Button ID="btnSubmitImage" runat="server" Text="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table><br />

Protected Sub btnSubmitImage_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitImage.Click
**insert code is here but it's not relevant so I'm omitting it**
Response.Write("<script>alert(" & "'Image Title added successfully'" & ")</script>")
Response.Redirect("AddToPicklist.aspx")
```

Comment: For now I am going to use `Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>{ alert('Image Title added successfully'); document.location.href = 'AddToPickList.aspx'; }</script>")`

I will look into using WebServices in my upcoming projects. The project I am working on right now is too time focused for me to try and learn anything new. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can answer your own question just so that it's resolved... :)

Comment: I had to enter a comment since my reputation isn't that high yet. It said something about answering after 6 hours :) But I will now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use `Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>{ alert('Image Title added successfully'); document.location.href = 'AddToPickList.aspx'; }</script>")`

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting within the same request, therefore the javascript you wish to output will never be rendered.

1 solution would be to pass a querystring to your next page like:

```
Response.Redirect("AddToPicklist.aspx?alert=titleadded")
```

Then on `AddToPicklist.aspx` do:

```
If Request.QueryString("alert") = "titleadded" Then
   Response.Write("<script>alert(" & "'Image Title added successfully'" & ")</script>")
End If
```

Alternatively you could redirect to the page via javascript after the alert, but this would be bad for users who do not have javascript enabled.

---

On a side note, look into the use of `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` for outputting javascript, rather than `Response.Write`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Redirect will be making the page (or another page - not sure what your pages are called) reload from scratch and so the click event will not be entered again and the `<script>` will not be inserted.

I would advise against producing messages on the client by using `Response.Write`. At the very least use registerclientscriptblock eg

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock("showSaveMessage", _
  "<script language=""JavaScript""> _
      alert('Your changes have been saved.'); _
   </script>")
```

[(from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx)

But I would instead consider using a [WebService to write to your DB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx). And then you won't have to have a full postback.